# Vim: if specific version, then don't load plugin

Tags: vim, plugin

I wonder what the best way is to decide whether or not some plugin should be loaded depending on some specific compilation/version of Vim. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may also be interested in the dedicated [`vi` and Vim stackexchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to depend on the version, use this:

```
if version > 700
    "do stuff for version 7 and up
endif
```

If what you really want to know is whether a certain command works, you can use the `exists` statement:

```
if exists('+breakindent')
    set breakindent
endif
```

If it's being in a GUI that you care about, try `if has('gui_running')` or put the commands into `.gvimrc`.

Comment: Thanks. In particular, I would like to load a plugin if I happen to run in gVim or Macvim, but not otherwise. Maybe this implies that it's not the version I'm really looking for?

Comment: @gustafbstrom You can add stuff that's specific to gvim into `.gvimrc`. I don't know about macvim.

Comment: @gustafbstrom I just realized: You probably want to react to the gui. Try `if has('gui_running')`.